# Анимация текста через Qjuery не работает

Tags: javascript

```js
var diraction = "right";
var offset0 = 0;

if (diraction === "right") {
  var movingRight = function() {
    $("#heading").offset({
      left: offset0
    });
    offset0++;
  };
  var movingRightId = setInterval(movingRight, 30);
  if (offset0 === 200) {
    clearInterval(movingRightId);
    diraction = "down";
    offset0 = 0;
  }
} else if (diraction === "down") {
  var movingDown = function() {
    $("#heading").offset({
      top: offset0
    });
    offset0++;
  };
  var movingDownId = setInterval(movingDown, 30);
  if (offset0 === 200) {
    clearInterval(movingDownId);
    diraction = "left";
    offset0 = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Hello world!</h1>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Я пытаюсь написать написать код, который сначала будет двигать надпись "Hello world" на 200 пикселей влево, а потом на 200 пикселей вниз. Но при запуске, ничего не происходит. Где ошибка?

Comment: На данный момент ошибка здесь `if (offset0 = 200)`.

Comment: @РустамГимранов исправил ошибку с if (offset0 = 200), но код по прежнему работает не коректно, теперь надпись все время двигается вправо и не меняет свое направление на "вниз" после 200 пикселей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var diraction = "right";
var offset0 = 0;

function move() {
  var movingRight = function() {
    $("#heading").offset({
      left: offset0
    });
    offset0++;
  };
  var movingDown = function() {
    $("#heading").offset({
      top: offset0
    });
    offset0++;
  };
  if (diraction === "right") {
    if (offset0 === 200) {
      diraction = "down";
      offset0 = 0;
    } else {
      movingRight();
    }
  } else if (diraction === "down") {
    if (offset0 === 200) {
      diraction = "left";
      offset0 = 0;
    } else {
      movingDown();
    }
  }
}
setInterval(move, 30);
```

```css
#heading {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Hello world!</h1>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Работа с [таймерами](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval) обычно строится по следующей схеме:

```
// Объявляем id таймера.
var movingId;

// Функция, которая будет выполняться.
var moving = function() {
  // Здесь при определенных условиях удаляем таймер.
  clearInterval(movingId);

  // Если нужно, то запускаем таймер вновь.
  movingId = setInterval(moving, 10);
}

// Запускаем первый таймер.
movingId = setInterval(moving, 10);
```

```js
var movingId,
  position = 'left',
  offset = 0;

var moving = function() {
  $("#heading").offset({
    [position]: offset++
  });

  // Если нужна поддержка старых браузеров
  // var offseting = {};
  // offseting[position] = offset++;
  // $("#heading").offset(offseting);

  // Если достигли отступ в 200px.
  if (200 === offset) {
    // Очищаем таймер.
    clearInterval(movingId);

    // Если позиция смещения была слева.
    if ('left' === position) {
      // Меняем позицию смещения.
      position = 'top';

      // Сбрасываем отступ.
      offset = 0;

      // Запускаем таймер для движения вниз.
      movingId = setInterval(moving, 10);
    }
  }
}

// Запускаем таймер для смены позиции слева.
movingId = setInterval(moving, 10);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#heading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Hello world!</h1>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```