# Создать анимацию с помощью setInterval

Tags: javascript, анимация, setinterval

При прочтении книги в ней попалась задачка, вроде пустяк, но я никак не могу понять, как правильно это реализовать, подскажите кто нибудь.

Сама задача:
"Используйте setInterval для анимации заголовка h1, двигая
его по квадрату, вдоль краев страницы. Пусть он переместится
на 200 пикселей вправо, на 200 пикселей вниз, 200 пикселей
влево, 200 пикселей вверх, а затем начнет с начала. Подсказка:
нужно запоминать текущее направление (вправо, вниз, влево
или вверх), чтобы знать, увеличивать или уменьшать для заголовка отступы слева (left) и сверху (top). Кроме того, при
достижении угла квадрата нужно будет менять направление."

Comment: Покажите попытку решить задачу, а мы уже подскажем что не так. Вообще в подсказке и так написано как решать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Анимация текста через Qjuery не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998105/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-qjuery-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const h = document.querySelector('h1');

let leftOffset = 0; //начальный отступ слева
let topOffset = 0; //начальный отступ сверху
let direction = 'right'; //начальное направление

setInterval(() => { 

  switch(direction) {
    case 'right':
      //если движемся в право, увеличиваем отступ слева на единицу
      leftOffset++;
      //когда отступ достиг 200 сменяем направление на "вниз"
      if(leftOffset === 200) direction = 'bottom';
      break;
    case 'bottom':
      //если движемся в вниз, увеличиваем отступ сверху на единицу
      topOffset++;
      //когда отступ достиг 200 сменяем направление на "влево"
      if(topOffset === 200) direction = 'left';
      break;
    case 'left':
      //если движемся в влево, уменьшаем отступ слева на единицу
      leftOffset--;
      //когда отступ достиг 0 сменяем направление на "вверх"
      if(leftOffset === 0) direction = 'top';
      break;
    case 'top':
      //если движемся в вверх, уменьшаем отступ сверху на единицу
      topOffset--;
      //когда отступ достиг 0 сменяем направление на "вправо"
      if(topOffset === 0) direction = 'right';
      break;
  }
  
  //задаем элементу измененные отступы
  h.style.top = topOffset + 'px';
  h.style.left = leftOffset + 'px';
  
}, 5);
```

```css
h1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>s</h1>
```

Comment: Неплохо было бы оставить комментарии, очевидно что автор только изучает язык

Comment: @Vearo сделано)